# What is the difference between javax.ws.rs.client.Client and org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient

Tags: java, spring, jersey, client, webclient

I am trying to create a REST webservice caller in Spring, but I don't know which is the best solution if I try to add a basic authentication, should I use `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient`:

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(String baseAddress, List<?> providers, String username, String password, String configLocation)
```

or with Jersey `javax.ws.rs.client.Client`:

```
HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic("howtodoinjava", "password");
clientConfig.register( feature) ;
clientConfig.register(JacksonFeature.class);

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient( clientConfig );
WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://localhost:8080/JerseyDemos/rest").path("employees");
```